# Wildcard for variable output

Tags: shell, sh

I have a list of the following variables:

```
abc1=1
abc2=2
qwerty=4
qwerty3=3
abc9=9
```

Is it possible somehow to output the value of all variables that begin with `abc`?

Something like wildcard: `printf "%s\n" "${abc*}"`

Comment: There is `echo ${!abc*}` but it only works in Bash, not sh

Comment: @KarlsD : You have tagged this as _sh_, which means old Unix shell (Bourne shell). Are you really still using this?

Comment: @user1934428 no, I am just trying to make my script the most compatible with other shells.

Comment: Then the elegant suggestion by _that other guy_ won't do for you :-(  Unfortunately I'm not aware of any POSIX compatible means to generate a list of all shell variables. Consequently, I don't see how to restrict them to those matching a certain pattern. I guess you can't restrict your problem to get a list of all **exported** variables? Then your task would be feasible in POSIX shell, and I suggest that you add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat brittle, but

```
set | grep '^abc'
```

will *basically* do what you ask.

The output from `set` includes function definitions; the function bodies will be indented, so they won't match the `grep` pattern. If you also want to exclude the names of functions whose names begin with `abc`, maybe simply add `| grep -vF '()'`; or refactor to a slightly more complex `sed` script:

```
set | sed -n '/()/d;/^abc/p'
```

If you wanted to print functions along with their bodies, that too could probably done in `sed` or Awk.